# the execute order of threads

Tags: c++, multithreading

The result of following code is:

```
main() : creating thread, 0
main() : creating thread, 1
main() : creating thread, 2
main() : creating thread, 3
main() : creating thread, 4
Hello World! Thread ID, 0
Hello World! Thread ID, 1
Hello World! Thread ID, 2
Hello World! Thread ID, 3
Hello World! Thread ID, 4
```

I don't know why the thread is execute after all the `main()` finished, for example, after `cout << "main() : creating thread, " << i << endl;` a new thread created, so why the result is not

```
main() : creating thread, 0
Hello World! Thread ID, 0
.......



#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <pthread.h>

using namespace std;

#define NUM_THREADS     5

void *PrintHello(void *threadid)
{
   long tid;
   tid = (long)threadid;
   cout << "Hello World! Thread ID, " << tid << endl;
   pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main ()
{
   pthread_t threads[NUM_THREADS];
   int rc;
   int i;
   for( i=0; i < NUM_THREADS; i++ ){
      cout << "main() : creating thread, " << i << endl;
      rc = pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, 
                          PrintHello, (void *)i);
      if (rc){
         cout << "Error:unable to create thread," << rc << endl;
         exit(-1);
      }
   }
   pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

Comment: You should always join running threads. Anything else (besides special cases) is no good.

Comment: add a call to `join` as in `threads[i].join();` after it's created. Or in a separate loop after the creation loop.

Comment: Putting the call to threads[i].join() inside the loop would be kind of a silly thing to do, since then the main thread would block until each thread had exited, and therefore only one thread would ever be running at a time -- which defeats the purpose of spawning multiple threads.  So definitely put the calls to join() in a separate loop after the creation loop.